# How to update window.location.hash on button click & scroll? (using History API)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, window.location

## Navigation:

- I'm creating a navigation bar for a site which contains 4 dots (vertical dot navigation), when the user hovers over it, it expands and links appear using a GSAP timeline.
- I'm also using the history API to update the location hash on scroll (which works perfectly with just the scroll), which uses the replaceState method.

## Problem:

- When the user is hovered over the navigation bar and clicks on the links, the location hash doesn't update and instead stays the same (the same hash that the user is on).
- I believe it has something to do with the function that actually scrolls the site, but cant put my finger on it.
- I also get a horrible error in the console, I've done some research but can only see things related to Angular (which I'm not familar with).

  > ("Throttling history state changes to prevent the browser from hanging.")

## Code:

```
$(window).on("scroll", checkPosition);

/*
Scroll To Anchor Function
*/

        $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var speed = 800;

            var target = this.hash;
            var $target = $(target);

            if(position != target){

                //Scroll to
                $('html, body').animate({
                    'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
                }, speed, 'swing', function() {
                   //Callback onced finished animating
                });


            } else {
                wiggleElement($(".circle"));
            }

        });

/* 
Update Location Hash
*/
        function checkPosition() {
            var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();

            $("section").each(function(){
                var section_pos = $(this).offset().top - 100;
                var section_height = $(this).height();

                if (section_pos <= scrolled && section_pos + section_height > scrolled) {
                    position = '#' + $(this).attr('id');

                    if(history.replaceState) {
                        history.replaceState(null, null, position);
                    }
                    else {
                        location.hash = position;
                    }

                    $('.circle').removeClass("current");
                    if (!is_open) {
                        $(position + '_circle').addClass("current");
                    }
                }
            })
        }
```

#### Many thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I can see, the hash is only updated in `checkPosition` - but this is only called for `scroll` events. The handler you have for `click` events on the links does nothing to `location.hash`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As the page is scrolling when the user clicks the button. I didn't think I would need to update it?

Comment: fair point, I'd missed that :)

Comment: I have tried adding the history.replaceState function when its finished scrolling, but the checkPosition() function doesn't work once after.

Comment: So the position variable works after the button has been clicked, and changes section accordingly. But the replaceState function doesn't. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't know what throttling was, which was the error of my ways.

I have throttled the checkPosition function and all is working.

Courtesy of Ben Alman:
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/